The simulation in DipTrace 5
I have created a schematic, see attached screenshot. Now I am trying to simulate how it works in digital Spice simulator (built in DipTrace 5.0 beta).

digital Spice simulator (built in DipTrace 5.0 beta).
In general, it works almost reasonable. But there are strange signal distortions on some outputs of U3 on each falling edge of the clock coming to the input of decade counter U5. I shown the problem with red marks.

What I am doing wrong? Is it simulator issue or the schematic is incorrect?
